# evenhandler not getting called when executed from UnitTest Code in WP7

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-phone-7

I m doing unit test for one of my app in WP7. I want to check whether the button_click function works properly. When I try to call the button_click function from my unit testcode
like below

```
        CheckUrVacabolary.MainPage cpage = new CheckUrVacabolary.MainPage();
        cpage.txtFind.Text = "home";
        cpage.butMeaning_Click(cpage,null);
```

But the eventhandler(OnDefineInDictCompleted) inside the button_click(OnDefineInDictCompleted)
is not getting called. Here is the code

```
    internal void butMeaning_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        graphPass.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        graphFail.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        if (txtFind.Text.ToString() != "Enter the word")
        {
            butNext.IsEnabled = true;
            DictServiceSoapClient client = GetDictServiceSoapClient();
            String meaningfor;
            if (txtRandomWord.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
            {
                txtRandomWord.Text = "";
                meaningfor = wordToGuess;
            }
            else
            {
                meaningfor = txtFind.Text.Trim().ToString();
            }

            if (meaningfor.Length != 0)
            {
                client.DefineInDictCompleted +=
                    new EventHandler<DefineInDictCompletedEventArgs
                            (OnDefineInDictCompleted);
                client.DefineInDictAsync("gcide", meaningfor);
            }
        }
    }
```

I m not using MVVM model in my app. Is there any way I could call the event handler also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer would be: do use MVVM nonetheless. One of its benefits is easier unit testing. But if you choose not to, you should make a separate method in a service-like class that is called by the event handler but can also be called from a unit test.

The method should contain only the business logic you want to test and not the UI behaviour. (With a view model you could even test UI behaviour, because it is abstracted). That means it should have arguments for the values you obtain from controls like `txtRandomWord`.

The event handler that `client` connects to is a problem.

First, the life cycle of each `client` instance you create by pressing the button is extended to that of the page, which introduces a potential [memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662842/how-do-events-cause-memory-leaks-in-c-and-how-do-weak-references-help-mitigate-t).

Second, I assume `OnDefineInDictCompleted` is a method in your page, so you should extract that from the page as well in a way that it is accessible to unit tests. If that method touches UI elements, this may be a real headache. Again, a strong case for a view model.